# Get previous column address

Tags: excel, vba

I have a named cell, and I want to start searching values from this row, but from the previous column.
This is the code I have:

```
'I use the "false false" for not having an absolute reference, I don't know if this will have any impact later ?
newAdres = SearchForTotal(Range("total1").Address(False, False))
```

And this is the function itself:

```
Function SearchForTotal(givenLocation As Variant) As Variant
    Debug.Print givenLocation
    Debug.Print Range(givenLocation).Offset(, -1)
```

The first debug gives me: "**U84**", the second gives me: "**0**" , while I would like to have ***T*84** instead

Comment: The cell `T84` is empty/or 0 I guess. You are not returning it's address but it's content by default. Not sure what you'd need it for but `.Offset(, -1).Address(False, False)` would return the address. If you plan to work with ranges, I'd also suggest to use the appropriate variables end `Set` these ranges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't give your function an address/string give the function the cell/range. `Variant` is the worst type you can use in VBA.

```
Function SearchForTotal(ByVal givenLocation As Range) As Range
    Debug.Print givenLocation.Address
    Debug.Print givenLocation.Offset(0, 1).Address

    ' return the offset cell
    Set SearchForTotal = givenLocation.Offset(0, 1)
End Function
```

Then call your function like

```
Dim NewCell As Range
Set NewCell = SearchForTotal(Range("total1"))

Debug.Print NewCell.Address
```

Always work with ranges/cells and use addresses/strings only for displaying purpose.

Comment: nicely explained as usual :)

Comment: Thanks @Pᴇʜ for your answer, firstly I hadn't the "set NewCell = ..." I only had "NewCell = ..." and I got an error, what is this "Set" doing exactly ?

Comment: You need to use `Set` with objects. Because `SearchForTotal` is returning a `Range` which is an object you need to use `Set` to assign this object to the variable. If you want to assign a value to the variabe then it is without `Set`. • That is why I recommended not to use `Variant` if possible. Because `Variant` can be a value or an object. It is not defined. So it makes things more difficult to understand and it's slow.

Comment: Ok, my function is a bit more complex and I'm stuck again :( I've edit my question, could you look again please ?

Comment: @smirnoff103 please don't change the question to a new one. We can only answer one question per post and your origanal one was solved. Therefore please remove your edit and start a new post for your new question.

Comment: Ok i'm sorry, I will create a new answer then.